# linux + virtualenv + pip using some system packages

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I would like to reuse certain packages installed systemwide, while ignoring all others.

I created `mkvirtualenv --distribute --extra-search-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython myenv` (defaulting to `--no-system-packages`, but `pip freeze` has no knowledge of ipython package.

Is there a way to pickup certain packages already installed system wide (`ipython`, `numpy`, etc)?

Thanks

Comment: Submitted as suggestion to https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/246

Comment: And this is being noted for pip at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely what you are looking for, but you can create a custom bootstrap script like this:

http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#creating-your-own-bootstrap-scripts